# Catch a Bad Request Exception (400)

Tags: java, exception, bad-request

My Facade/EJB is a simple method.In this method I make something like:

```
if(!something.isempty()){
do something;
else{
throw new BadRequestException("Something is missing");
```

In controller I call EJB and make a method which parameters cannot be null.Then I try to catch exception like this:

```
   try{
    something;
    catch(BadRequestException ex){
    makeSomethin;}´
```

The problem is that i don´t cach exception...

Comment: Because your BadRequestException has been wrapped inside another exception maybe ?

Comment: If you're not catching the exception it's either because it's not being thrown inside the `try` range or because the two exception classes are somehow different from each other.  (Or because some other `try` catches it first.)

Comment: "...the two exception classes are somehow different". What do you mean different? If I have a sql exception before my badrequestexception is never catched. I ´m saying that because i tried not introduncing values to "force" badrequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve my problem. In my Web method I was using the annotation NotNull, which means that exception is never called.